# Ruby colorize a section of text

Tags: ruby

I am writing a command line script in ruby and I am trying to color a section of lines. Currently, I am using the 'colorize' gem, but from the documentation it only lets you color one line of text at a time

```
puts "test".colorize(:green)
puts "test".colorize(:green)
puts "test".colorize(:green)
```

But, that seems a bit redundant to me and I would like to color all the lines of text, but only call 'colorize(:green)' once and not 3 times.

How can this be done in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Define a method for this:

```
def putsg(text)
  puts text.colorize(:green)
end
```

And than call that method:

```
putsg "test"
putsg "test"
putsg "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
puts ["test", "test", "test"].join($/).colorize(:green)
```

or

```
puts ["test", "test", "test"].map{|s| s.colorize(:green)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your statement *"...but from the documentation it only lets you color one line of text at a time"*

You can colorize different parts of the same line with different colors.

`s = "Hello"
ss = "world"
puts "#{s.red} #{"there".white} #{s.blue}"`

You can also accomplish your aim like this:

`s = "test"
puts "#{s}\n#{s}\n#{s}".green`

Or:

`s1 = "check"
s2 = "this"
s3 = "out"
puts "#{s1}\n#{s2}\n#{s3}".green`

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a method like this:
The input is the color you want as a string and the text you want outputed. This will work in the command prompt.

```
  def colorized_text(color,text)
    #Find colors here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit
    color_code_hash = {
        'red' => 196,
        'green' => 40,
        'yellow' => 226,
        'blue' => 27,
    }
    puts"\e[38;5;#{color_code_hash[color]}m#{text}\e[0m"
  end
```

I found this to be much better than using the colorize gem since that only gives you 8 colors. You can find all the colors on the ansi escape wiki page under the 8 bit section.